# Convert unicode to a list of string?

Tags: python

I get to Python function a list from url.
The string:

```
u'[\\'AAA',u\\'BBB\\']'
```

How can I convert it to:

```
['AAA',u'BBB']
```

or do I need to send the post with the data in the url another way?

This is html side:

```html
<form name="input" action="/automationreport/{{mydata}}/" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="sendReport" value="Send Report"/></form>
mydata=<type 'list'>: ['AAA', u'BBB']
```

Comment: How did you get that first unicode?

Comment: Maybe you mean `u'[\'AAA\',u\'BBB\']'` instead? Your actual string gives syntax error in Python.

Comment: Your string is not well formatted, it's impossible to do something with this.

Comment: this is html side:
<form name="input" action="/automationreport/{{mydata}}/" method="post"><input type="submit" class="sendReport" value="Send Report"/></form>
mydata=<type 'list'>: ['AAA', u'BBB']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this  i am not sure whether it is your required outcome

```
x = u"[\'AAA',u\'BBB\']"
a=x.split()
for i in a :
    print i
```

it will give the result `['AAA',u'BBB']`

Answer (score -2):

`x = u'[\'AAA',u\'BBB\']'`

`eval(x)`

Comment: Why using eval is bad : 1.There is almost always a better way to do it
2. Very dangerous and insecure
3. Makes debugging difficult
4. Slow